# Apache2 symlink - How to use target name and MIME type

Tags: 20.04, apache2, symbolic-link

I just set up an Apache2 server and it works fine. Since this server purpose is to simply serve versioned files, I created a `latest` symlink which targets *e.g.* `myfile_v1.1.0.ext`.

The problem is that when I access the URL `http://localhost/latest`, the download window shows `latest` as the filename and `application/octet-stream` as MIME type.

I would like that when I access this same URL, it shows `myfile_v1.1.0.ext` as the filename and `application/my-app` as MIME type.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is the symlink pointing to a directory that is hosted on a Samba share?

Comment: No it does not. It points to a directory which is part of an ext4 filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use an Alias in the Apache configuration. The downside is that you'll need to update this every time there's a release, but the benefit is that you can have a greater degree of control over how the file is handled.

Here is how you can do it:

0. Edit the Apache `.conf` file for the site
1. Add this in the `<VirtualHost>` section:

   ```
   Alias "/download" "/path/to/releases/myfile_v1.1.0.ext"
   <Directory "/path/to/releases">
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride All

           <FilesMatch "\.(ext|zip)$">
                   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1209600, public"
                   ForceType application/tar+gzip
           </FilesMatch>
   </Directory>
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `application/tar+gzip` with the proper content type for the file.</sup>
2. Save the file and restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Feel free to switch `restart` with `reload`.</sup>
3. Test the url by visiting `your.site/download`

This has been tested on Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS with Apache 2.4.41

Comment: It does not really work... The filename still is proposed as `latest` (or `download` in your example). However, thanks to your suggestion, I found a way to got this working. I'll reply to the post with an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply add a `Redirect` directive in the Apache configuration file for your website.

```
Redirect "/latest" "files/myfile_v1.1.0.ext"
```